# Printing the whole list wont show all elements from the txt

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, printing

I've been trying to print the whole txt which I open in the first line. First 3 methods wont print the whole list, and the last one does but i dont know how to format it to seaparate each element in its row.

```
myList = open("LIST.txt","r").readlines()
#print(*myList, sep='\n')
#for elem in myList:
       # print (elem) 
#print ('\n'.join(myList))
print(myList[0:])
```

Comment: What do you mean, they don't show all elements? Are you confused because the output doesn't have the brackets and stuff?

Comment: nope, the output looks just fine, but not the whole list is shown, just the last part of the list [:-100] lets say

Comment: You've got some other issue, then, because the commented-out options should print all elements just fine. (They'll all have a bunch of extra blank lines between the lines from the file, but all lines from the file should show up.) Are the earlier lines just scrolling off the top of your terminal?

Comment: No there are no lines, but if I print it as print(myList[0:]) it prints everything, but i would like to have it separated in rows.

Answer (score 1):

All of those methods seem to print out all lines:

```
>>> my_list = open("list.txt").readlines()
>>> for elem in my_list:
...     print (elem)
...
First line

Second line

Third line

>>> my_list = open("list.txt").readlines()
>>> for elem in my_list:
...     print (elem)
...
First line

Second line

Third line

>>> print ('\n'.join(my_list))
First line

Second line

Third line

>>> print (''.join(my_list))
First line
Second line
Third line

>>> print(my_list[:])
['First line\n', 'Second line\n', 'Third line\n']
```

If `myList[0:]` works, you could use join with it: `''.join(myList[0:])`.  However, if you're joining lines back together you may simply want `read` instead of `readlines`:

```
>>> print(open("list.txt").read())
First line
Second line
Third line
```

Comment: So confusing, i still dont get it from the first line of the list.txt. I simply have a txt with a tuple of strings like this "SBCOB_BC3219-255|(10)|M" , in each row one string, wich has been copied from excel. And i just want to print each string in a row, but for all of them.

Comment: @fekstefek, maybe it's the console window you're printing them in is cutting off the beginning of the scroll buffer? I'm not sure what might be going on.

Comment: ok, that may be the problem, why do such thing occur and how can i avoid them?

Comment: @fekstefek: terminal/console windows tend to have a finite buffer. The size of that buffer really depends on the terminal program you're using. You could avoid this altogether by printing out to a file and then checking that file later.